# function with no return type

Tags: c++, parameters, return-type

I just have 2 quick questions, I'm hoping someone can clarify for me.

1. When writing a function is the input paramater list the same as the parameters?
2. when a function has no return type is the "return 0;" just left out of the function code?

For example if I was to write a function that used to integers in its input parameter list with no return type would this be the proper  way to write it?:

```
int convertTemp( int a, int b) {}
```

Comment: When a function has no return type, returning 0 would be an error, because 0 is an `int`.

Comment: Also, not to be too pedantic, a "function" that does not return anything is not a function, but a routine.

Comment: @Sparky: Or a subroutine, or a procedure, depending on your choice of terminology. In C++ terminology, it's still a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  int convertTemp( int a, int b) {}
```

should be:

```
 void convertTemp( int a, int b) {}
```

if function does not return anything, `int` means the function's return type is `int`. Note that you can still have `return` statements in a function that with return type `void`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer above that the return type should be changed to void,
And when asking the first question you need to distinguish between formal and actual parameters.
Formal parameters are a and b in the function definition:

`void func (int a, int b) {}`

whereas the actual parameters are 2 and 3 in the function call:

`func (2,3)`

where 2 is copied to a and 3 is copied to b.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make the return type `void`

```
void convertTemp( int a, int b) {
    //do stuff...
    return;  //optional, but a good habit to get in to
}
```

Comment: `return` is optional at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

1. The input parameter list is a list of type and names of the inputs. These are passes as a list of values in the calling code.
2. If you have no return value, then the function is declared with a `void` return type, and should not have a value given in the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `void` return type to declare a function will return nothing:

```
void convertTemp( int a, int b) {
}
```

Now, how would the function convert a Temp when it returns nothing?

It should definitely not modify some state behind the scenes (like global variables).

Returning the converted value is what I would expect.

The void return type would have to be changed to the type of the conversion result.

I would definitely investigate when faced with code like the above.